# How to add a language syntax to AWS Cloud9

Tags: syntax, aws-cloud9, lilypond

I'm trying to add the Lilypond language syntax to AWS Cloud9.

In my searching, I've found [ajaxorg/ace/tool](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/tree/master/tool) and [textmate/lilypond.tmbundle](https://github.com/textmate/lilypond.tmbundle) on Github.org

I've tried cloning both repositories and I've run:

```
$ npm install
$ node add_mode.js Lilypond "ly|ily|lily"
$ node tmlanguage.js ../../lilypond.tmbundle/Syntaxes/Lilypond.tmLanguage
```

But I can't find any documentation on how to implement the result into the AWS Cloud9 IDE. What am I missing?